# Error 500 on Websocket, deploying Django-app on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, websocket

I'm having some problems with websockets that I don't have locally. The problem is that heroku is telling me that there is a 500 error.

My settings on prod:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'config.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis_url")]
        },
    },
}
```

My ASGI.py

```
import django

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from my_app.chat import (
    routing,
)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

I'm ready using wss instead of ws, and that not the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see the 500 error?  In your original request?  In the websocket hookup?  Please be as precise as possible.   You have a lot of moving parts.

Comment: Hello @TimRoberts I can see error 500 in js console:
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'wss://herokuapp/ws/chat/random/' failed: Unexpected response code: 500